# Can I use this equation for prediction?

Tags: regression, correlation, forecasting, prediction, descriptive-statistics

I've got a question. Below you see a graph which shows the regression equation between construction activities in the private sector (X axis) in £bn and the total amount of all construction activities in several sectors (Y axis) in £bn.

Can I use this equation for forecasting? Yes or no, and why or why not?

[image]

Comment: forecasting implies a time component, but I don't see this mentioned anywhere in question.

Answer (score 0):

you would need to have future predictions for X the private sector. Having said that you could use your equation , I think that you should not. You need to identify the relation between X and Y in such away that you incorporate possible lag effects of X and perhaps some forma of an ARMA component to account for other memory structure along with possible changes in levels/trends over time while adjusting for unusual values that if left untreated will bias your coefficients.